# regex works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some code that is executed when a submission button is clicked. The code works on desktop but not on mobile. Not sure whats causing the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){



emailSubmitButton.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputWidth = emailNameInput.width(),
        submitWidth = emailSubmitButton.width(),
        submitTotal = inputWidth + submitWidth + 38,
        userEmail = emailNameInput.val(),
        windowWidth = $(window).width();

    var errorMessage = function(error){
        emailError.html(error);
        if (windowWidth > 501) {
            emailError.css({opacity: '1', display: 'block', width: submitTotal});
        }
        else {
            emailError.css({opacity : '1', display : 'block', width : '96%', marginLeft : '2%'})
        }

    };

    if(!userEmail){
        errorMessage('Please enter your email');
    }
    else{
        if(userEmail == "Enter email..."){
            errorMessage('Please enter your email');
        }
        else
        {
            if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(userEmail))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "emailSubmit.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {type: "emailSubmit", email: userEmail},
                    success: function (response) {
                        JSON.stringify(response);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        JSON.stringify(err);
                    },
                    complete : function() {
                        //$('.user-accept').addClass('unhide');
                        $('.at-wrapper').animate({
                            opacity : 0
                        }, 2000)
                    }

                });
                $('.user-accept').css({width : submitTotal});
            } else {
                errorMessage('Invalid email, please try again');
                console.log(userEmail);
            }

        }
    }

});
})
```

Any ideas as to what the problem might be? Is there something on mobile that acts differently?

Comment: output your error in `.error` to see ?

Comment: Check that the mobile browser allows JS execution?

Comment: how would i output .error?

Comment: Usually, desktop browser supports more modern version of Javascript as compared to Mobile devices. Try finding your mobile browser supported javascript version.